# Building up a movable viewport for a workspace

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport, implementation

I want to implement a very huge workspace for placing objects onto it, but for convenient working  I want to make a special "viewport" which shows a portion of workspace for user and this "viewport" can be resized or moved within the workspace. For instance, in Photoshop, when you zoom in an image, you see only some part of it and then you can go to the place you want to edit.

How can I implement this in HTML?

Comment: Maybe an HTML canvas can help, depending on your use case.

Comment: I need to place <div>, <p> and <svg> elements on the workspace, so, as I think, canvas is not a viable solution in my case.

Comment: You might try CSS `transform: scale(scaleratio);` on the parent element...

Comment: Please show what you have tried already so we can help you take steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some CSS `transform: scale();` to do it:

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="range"]').addEventListener('input', e => {
  document.querySelector('.resizable').style.setProperty('--size', e.target.value)
})
```

```css
.container{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.resizable{
  transform: scale(var(--size));
  transform-origin: top left;
  --size:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="resizable">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.   Sed turpis nibh, volutpat in egestas ac, pellentesque ac lacus. Curabitur at aliquam mi. Nullam nec imperdiet urna. Maecenas sodales malesuada urna, auctor mattis orci. Etiam purus erat, cursus quis nunc faucibus, mollis scelerisque nisi. Nullam sit amet commodo nisi. Proin aliquet quis leo ac rutrum. Curabitur dignissim, augue vel rutrum viverra, tellus mi rutrum elit, aliquam vulputate ipsum augue et ante. Proin lacinia erat ut risus lacinia congue. Nulla ac commodo metus, at viverra mi. Fusce aliquet sodales vulputate. Fusce a tempus nibh, id pharetra lacus. Cras pulvinar congue lacus at aliquet. Nam consequat fringilla augue vel faucibus. Proin non gravida purus. Aenean ut faucibus sem.</div>
  </div>
</div>
Drag me to resize the lorem ipsum:<br/>
<input type="range" value="1" step="0.5" min="0.5" max="4" />
```

Try it on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/FZs111/pen/jObQgNm) (at least until the Stack Snippets server is down...)

Comment: That works almost as I want to, but there is still one issue. I create objects on the workspace by mouse click, and "position" of this elements is relative, so for getting the point where to place new object I do following:

object_x = e.clientX - workspace.getBoundingRect().left;

but when the workspace is resized, this position is calculated wrongly

Comment: Then you'll have to take the `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` of the `.container` into account, but that's a different topic...

Comment: I am sorry, I probably missclicked

Comment: @AlexTeexone Oh, no problem. I just wanted to know if there's a problem with my answer that I should fix...

Comment: Yeah, I faced some problem with structure you've recommended, but it is not connected with disappearing of the tick on your answer, it is just a lag, I think. I opened a new topic, so you can check it out by the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62038601/resizing-and-scrolling-issue-js-html/62040014?noredirect=1#comment109729759_62040014. If you have any ideas how to deal with it, it would be great

Comment: @AlexTeexone I'll take a look at it a bit later