# Resizing and scrolling issue (JS/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are two containers: the first is a small viewport and the second is huge workspace. So, user scroll the viewport to move within the workspace. I want to implement a zoom in/out feature via CSS property `tranform`, but during the process I faced one difficulty and could not find a precise solution for it.

The issue is: when user zooms in/out, elements at the workspace are shifted. This happens actually because the workspace is resized, not they. But if I resize each element at the workspace, the distances between them (in terms of `top/left` CSS values) will be changed, what is not preferred.

I see the following solution: change scrolls values after resizing, but I do not know what ratios or numbers to use. Is there any formulae or another solution to overcome such a problem?

For resizing use `Alt + MouseWheel`

```js
let workspace = document.getElementsByClassName('workspace')[0];
workspace.onwheel = resize;

let current_scale = 1;

function resize(E) {
  E = E || window.event
  if (E.altKey) {
    E.preventDefault();
    let new_scale = Math.max(0.1, current_scale - E.deltaY / 360);
    workspace.style.setProperty('transform', 'scale(' + new_scale + ')');
    current_scale = new_scale;
  }
}
```

```css
.viewport {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: scroll;
 
  transform: scale(1);
}

.workspace {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="workspace">
    <button class="element" style="top: 100px; left: 150px"></button>
    <button class="element" style="top 80px; left: 100px"></button>
    <button class="element" style="top: 230px; left: 130px"></button>
    <button class="element" style="top: 100px; left: 250px"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

***UPD***: I attached some photos from the original project for clarification:

So, that's a look of the workspace with `scale(1)`
[image: Scale(1)]

Then I resize it and get the following result:
[image: Resized]

But desirable result looks like this:
[image]

***UPD2***
I inserted `<svg>` element to show how lines are drawn and why resizing each button seems to me a not viable solution in my case

```js
 let workspace = document.getElementsByClassName('workspace')[0];
    workspace.onwheel = resize;
    let current_scale = 1;
    function resize(E) {
        E = E || window.event;
        if (E.altKey) {
            E.preventDefault();
            let new_scale = Math.max(0.1, current_scale - E.deltaY / 360);
            var btns = workspace.getElementsByClassName('element');
            for(var i = 0; i <btns.length; i++) {
                btns[i].style.setProperty('transform', 'scale(' + new_scale + ')');
            }
            current_scale = new_scale;
        }
    }
```

```css
.viewport {
            width: 80vw;
            height: 80vh;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow: scroll;

            transform: scale(1);
            transform-origin: 0 0;
        }

        .workspace {
            position: relative;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 1000px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .element {
            position: absolute;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
        }
        .line-drawer
        {
            position:absolute;
            height:1000px;
            width:1000px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="workspace">
        <svg class="line-drawer">
            <line x1="100px" x2="130px" y1="80px" y2="230px" style='stroke-width: 4px; stroke: black'></line>
        </svg>
        <button class="element" style="top: 100px; left: 150px"></button>
        <button class="element" style="top: 80px; left: 100px"></button>
        <button class="element" style="top: 230px; left: 130px"></button>
        <button class="element" style="top: 100px; left: 250px"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could set the `transform-origin:` property to `top left` but when zooming the elements need to shift in some direction right?

Comment: Not actually. I attached some pictures to make it more clear. The problem is that after resizing elements at the workspace are shifted, but they are not supposed to do it. The goal is to make elements just a bit larger/smaller, without shifting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaling the individual elements like this will keep them in there position

```js
let workspace = document.getElementsByClassName('workspace')[0];
workspace.onwheel = resize;

let current_scale = 1;

function resize(E) {
  E = E || window.event
  if (E.altKey) {
    E.preventDefault();
    let new_scale = Math.max(0.1, current_scale - E.deltaY / 360);
    var btns = workspace.getElementsByClassName('element');
    for(var i = 0; i <btns.length; i++) { 
        btns[i].style.setProperty('transform', 'scale(' + new_scale + ')');
    }
    current_scale = new_scale;
  }
}
```

```css
.viewport {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: scroll;
 
  transform: scale(1);
}

.workspace {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="workspace">
    <button class="element" style="top: 100px; left: 150px"></button>
    <button class="element" style="top 80px; left: 100px"></button>
    <button class="element" style="top: 230px; left: 130px"></button>
    <button class="element" style="top: 100px; left: 250px"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I draw lines between centers of some elements and if I follow such a strategy, the length of the lines will be decreased after resizing and if the initial distance is small, the lines are going to disappear at all after resizing.

Comment: That might be a different problem, It depends on how you draw the lines but if you do not target the line elements or the workspace in the `resize(E)` function they should remain unchanged.

Comment: I have just inserted one more code snippet to show how lines are organized in the original project. So if I resize only buttons, it seems the line is getting shorter when it is not supposed to. I mean if the initial line is short, resized buttons will overlap it. But if apply ```transform: scale ```to the ```workspace``` everything is fine expect a shifting issue. So, I think I should just scroll the viewport manually to imitate an effect that elements are just resized, not shifted.

Comment: It seems the lines are not between the centers, they run from the top-left corner of the first element to the top-left corner of the next element. The length of the line doesn't decrease in your example.

Comment: If I resize the workspace:
Init: https://ibb.co/QkZ0dGT
Result: https://ibb.co/mbyzSDP


If I resize each button:
Init: https://ibb.co/wMKMnML
Result: https://ibb.co/7kfyYb2

Comment: If you zoom, you need a fixed origin too zoom from. (e.g. the mouse position) The shifting you experience is needed if your lines need to get longer. This codepen has a good animation to show this. The black dot is the `transform-origin` I mentioned earlier: https://codepen.io/danwilson/pen/qXPdbw